# Auto-populating aggregation resulting field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity in my Spring Application that represents evaluations a document can have.

```
@Id
private String id;

@DbRef
private Document doc;

private List<ReportDetails> reports;

@Transient
private float average;
```

And the `ReportDetails` entity is defined like this :
    private String id;

```
@DBRef
private User user;

private String comment;

private int mark;

private Date date;
```

When I display those reports in my table, I would like to have a column named 'average'. I know I have to make an Aggregation to compute the average of each Report but, I'd like to paginate my reports and apply sorting on them.

How can I sort on the average ? Spring repositories won't let me do this, which kind of request will I have to build to populate automatically my "average" field without looping on each report to compute the average ?

Comment: You need to stop using `DBRef`. The type is as close to officially deprecated as you can get without there being an official notice yet. If you wanted to "aggregate" on this as a value, it's unsupported. If you wanted to use modern features such as [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ( which basically supersedes  the `DBRef` concept ) then it's also unsupported. On the more direct note, mongorepostory is only for "basic CRUD". Everything else you write in regular code.

Comment: Ok, good to know that is nearly deprecated. Just asking but I'm pretty sure to know the answer, is it possible to query a collection and for each record matching the request and aggregate all marks to create an average in the same query ?